# Java Compile Error - No Suitable Constructor

Tags: java, netbeans

I am new to the Java game, and am attempting to allow the user to select a directory, and have the contents of said directory recursively searched and printed.

My code gives me the error:

> No suitable constructor found for File(file)

On this line

```
File[] files = new File(chooser.getSelectedFile()).listFiles();
```

Will someone here be a gem and assist me in what would be the proper syntax to achieve my desired result? This is my full code:

```
    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                
    chooser = new JFileChooser(); 
    chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("."));
    chooser.setDialogTitle(choosertitle);
    chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
    // disable the "All files" option.
    chooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
    //    
    if (chooser.showOpenDialog(this) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) { 
        File[] files = new File(chooser.getSelectedFile()).listFiles();
    } else { System.out.println("No Selection "); }
}                                        


public static void showFiles(File[] files) {
    for (File file : files) {
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            System.out.println("Directory: " + file.getName());
            showFiles(file.listFiles()); 
        } else {
            System.out.println("File: " + file.getName());
        }
    }
}
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Find().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What is the return type of `chooser.getSelectedFile()`?

Comment: @SimonBerthiaume - it returns the directory of what the user selected.  For example: C:\users\jojo\Folder1       Does that answer your ?

Comment: Does it return the directory as a File object or a String? The [File object constructors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#constructor.summary) mostly takes Strings and URIs as inputs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`chooser.getSelectedFile()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#getSelectedFile()) already returns `File`, so you can call `listFiles()` directly on its return value:

```
File[] files = chooser.getSelectedFile().listFiles();
```

Comment: That removes the error - but I am not getting any directory and/or files written when I select a folder?

Comment: @user2932408 That's odd. Does the folder you select have directories and/or files that are accessible to the user running the program?

Comment: Yes - I selected C:\Users\Owner\Documents\NetBeansProjects and all that I have written to the Output is run:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 18 seconds)

Comment: @user2932408 How are you showing the files? You set a local variable `File[] files` but I don't see any code calling `showFiles()` method.

Comment: Maybe I am mistaken due to my noobness - but would this not print the names?  `System.out.println("Directory: " + file.getName());`

Comment: @user2932408 Right, but you never call the method that prints this. You need to add a call `showFiles(files)` after the dialog is closed.

Comment: Oh gosh - that was def a noob mistake!  Thank you kindly!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what chooser.getSelectedFile().listFiles() is returning but this might work

```
File[] files = chooser.getSelectedFile().listFiles();
```

Answer (score 0):

`chooser.getSelectedFile()` returns a File Object (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#getSelectedFile()). You already get a File Object. No need passing it as parameter to the File constructor (such a constructor doesn't exist by the way (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html)).

The method `listFiles()` lists all the files of a directory (the directory is the object which you call that method on) (See: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles() )

I think what you mean should be : `chooser.getSelectedFile().listFiles()`